# Application.ProcessMessages hangs?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl

my single threaded delphi 2009 app (not quite yet complete) has started to have a problem with   Application.ProcessMessages hanging.  my app has a TTimer object that fires every 100 ms to poll an external device.  i use Application.ProcessMessages to update the screen when something changes so the app is still responsive.

one of these was in a grid OnMouseDown event.  in there, it had an Application.ProcessMessages that essentially hung.  removing that was no problem except that i soon discovered another Application.ProcessMessages that was also blocking.

i think what may be happening to me is that the TTimer is--in the app mode i'm currently debugging--probably taking too long to complete.  i have prevented the TTimer.OnTimer event hander from re-entering the same code (see below):

```
procedure TfrmMeas.tmrCheckTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if m_CheckTimerBusy then
    exit;

  m_CheckTimerBusy:=true;
  try
    PollForAndShowMeasurements;
  finally
    m_CheckTimerBusy:=false;
  end;
end;
```

what places would it be a bad practice to call Application.ProcessMessages?  OnPaint routines springs to mind as something that wouldn't make sense.

any general recommendations?

i am surprised to see this kind of problem arise at this point in the development!

Comment: Why is this a CW? It seems to be a pretty specific and technical question to me.

Comment: @Sertac is right.  You don't have to mark a question as community wiki unless A) you want to invite low-rep users to edit your question, or B) you're asking a highly subjective poll question.  There's no rule *against* making your questions CW, but you and the people who answer them won't gain any reputation.

Comment: any reason why you're not considering introducing threading into your application?

Comment: ok; good to know about the Community Wiki.  

i have something i'd like to say about the SO community.  consider me an occasional user who is largely ignorant about the "finer points" of how questions are classified (closing questions, wiki, etc) in SO.  SO is an important tool for me to get help with some problems.  from my ignorant perspective, "closings" seem to be done ruthlessly.  the result is that i find i spend time thinking about how the question may be received by people "patrolling" SO.  my saying this will not make me popular but it's my opinion...

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen
yes--i do plan to use threading later (i did a proof of concept several months ago).  i haven't used threading for anything (important) yet so i am slow to adopt since we're late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you all for your comments/suggestions.

here i made a test app that has a timer routine that takes longer than the interval it is set for.  when i push button1, Application.ProcessMessages hangs.  my solution for now is to disable the timer during the timer routine.

later we plan to put the "device communications" in a thread.

thank you!
mp

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add('text 1');

  // this call blocks
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  memo1.Lines.Add('text 2');
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  iTime:cardinal;
begin
  // fix by adding this:  timer1.Enabled:=false;

  iTime:=GetTickCount;
  while GetTickCount-iTime<200 do
    ;

  // fix by adding this:  timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

end.

object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 286
  ClientWidth = 426
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 56
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 112
    Top = 8
    Width = 297
    Height = 233
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Memo1')
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Interval = 100
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 200
    Top = 144
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation regarding `TApplication.ProcessMessages` is to *never ever* use it - there simply isn't a good point to place it.

Imagine what calling it does: your application runs a message loop - where the windows messages (produced by OS, other apps, your app etc) are sequentially processed - and there, in the middle of one of the message-processings, you just re-run the whole message loop again, without having control over what messages will be processed, how much of them there will be, if any of the messages will enter its' own message loop... and if they have any reentrancy problems or not. That's what I call *inviting trouble*.

There are sometimes good reasons to process *some* windows messages (particularry to not hang other threads), or to process all messagess directed to a particular window, but this may be accomplished in more subtle ways, with more control.

If you *have to* do any processing in the main GUI thread, and you just want to update the interface, you may use the `TWinControl.Repaint` method to redraw the GUI elements.
If you want to keep the app responsive to user input, you basically have to use backgroud/worker threads.

Notice: in Delphi, while doing any lenghty processing in the main thread, especcially if waiting is involved, you are supposed to call `CheckSynchronize` periodically, to allow any other threads to synchonize with the main thread - they may (and probably will) hang otherwise.
VCL calls this only when the app goes idle and when it processes the `WM_NULL` message (that is supossed to do nothing, which may cause some interesting side-effects too).

Comment: I agree what Viktor Svuk said. If you have some part of code that does lengthy calculations, its no good idea to do them in main thread. Its a bad programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use madExcept and you will see where is the deadlock.

Comment: that's an idea i hadn't thought MadExcept would catch because the app doesn't seem hung because--in so many ways--it looks like it's running ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems terrible style to rely heavily on timer-based logic, and you understand that as you say you are planning to use threads in the future.

Here's the progression in your code:

1. You have a timer window message. it does a small job.
2. Six months later, your timer is running a lot of code.
3. you think you could make things better by putting in Application.ProcessMessages.

Let's zoom in a little, on a timer with 100 msec interval, for a worst case:

```
09:00:00.000 - timer event fires
09:00:00.100 - we are half way through our Timer Event code. We hit an Application.ProcessMessages.
09:00:00.101 - timer event fires again, but the first time into it, has not yet completed.
09:00:00.200 - we are half way through our timer event code, the second time,
and hit APplication.ProcessMessages again.
```

Can you see the... Can you see the.... Can you see the..... problem here?

W

Comment: yes; the previous versions of the app used a slower (1000 ms) timer fine.  partway through this development cycle they told me the polling rate.  the other parts of this project are already quite ambitious and also behind schedule...no time to "reach" farther and put it in a thread yet--especially since my experience with threads is *almost* 0.  thank you for your comment!